# Why this error will be raised in GWT Server when i am trying to call my GWT application?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Here in below i am posting the one problem what i am getting in my project.

```
An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
Internal Error (constantPoolOop.cpp:67), pid=5160, tid=2796 Error: 
guarantee(error != (symbolOop)0,"tag mismatch with resolution error table") Java VM:
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode windows-x86)
An error report file with more information is saved as:

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit
http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

closed
When this error will display my GWT server will closed automatically.

Comment: This is a JVM bug, not caused by your code (even if your code is incorrect you should not get one of these). I would suggest trying a different JVM, better if it is a more updated one.

Comment: bug/internal error. Anyway, not meant for you.

Comment: you mean that restart the application or entire java will be using the new version.Give me full information about that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment this is a JVM bug. Just, I have been restarted my eclipse, it started working application with no issues.

After eclipse restarting also, getting the same problem better try restarting the system and try.